# Heroku app not working with custom domain

Tags: node.js, heroku, namecheap

I deployed a node app on heroku and pointed a custom domain to it from namecheap. When I type my domain in it will load a page that says "Theres nothing there, yet" and changes the url to domain.com.herokudns.com

After looking around for 2 days I came back to the same solution, I created two cname records on namecheap that pointed to the "domain.com.herokudns.com". The cname records automatically place a period after this target, when I place a period after my domain when searching, my website loads.

Is there a way to fix this? I've seen people with similar problems but I find it weird that my site will load both with www and without if I have a period at the end.

Comment: How did you "point" your domain to Heroku? Are you using HTTP 301 or 302 redirects? It's strange that the address bar would change. Are you able to share your URL?

Comment: When you add a custom domain to Heroku it gives you a url to point to, for example mine is thedankoe.com and it tells me to redirect to thedankoe.com.herokudns.com. I added this in namecheap as a cname record.

Comment: I see a CNAME for `www.thedankoe.com`, and that domain works for me: http://www.thedankoe.com/

Comment: See when I click on that link it just takes me to a heroku page that says there is nothing there. But once I place a period at the end it loads my page.

Comment: Maybe your browser has cached it? Try opening it in an incognito window. You didn't add an entry to your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), did you?

Comment: I just got off live chat with namecheap and this was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the cname record to a www name with the target of [herokuappname].herokuapp.com and add a url redirect @ to http://[www.yourdomain.tld]. After clearing my cache this worked.